# Azure site to site vpn alternate route (Backup internet connection)

Tags: azure

First off We have an existing Site-Site VPN (route based) between our office and our Azure cloud. This works exactly as it's supposed to.
Recently we've been working on setting up a cellular internet backup to guard against the proverbial construction worker with a backhoe problem. The internet backup is functional, and I've set up an alternate connection with the IP address of our backup option, but the site-site VPN never comes back up when we do a fail over test.
Functionally, on the "local" side, the same firewall is initiating the connection, so what I've done is set up the backup connection to use the same PSK, but to the ip of the backup internet rather than our "normal" IP.

I'm not certain what I've misconfigured, but I'm curious if anyone else has done something similar in Azure, and if so, how did you get it to work.

Comment: This should be on ServerFault, not StackOverflow. That said: when you post there, you should include configuration details. Otherwise, you're just going to get guesses.

Comment: Thanks David- I actually followed a "support" link from Azure's Site-Site VPN object to end up here. I'll jump over to ServerFault.